# Can I use SSL certificate generated for a specific website for an rdp session

Tags: rdp

On our Windows Server 2008 R2 we host a website.  This website uses an SSL certificate generated by a certificate authority.  During a recent security scan of the server, we discovered that the rdp service is using a self-signed certificate which is not considered safe.  Can I assign that SSL certificate we bought for our website to the rdp service or is there some differences between SSL certificates used by a website, vs server certificates?  The certificate, under "this certificate has been verified for the following uses" says both "SSL Client Certificate" and "SSL Server Certificate"
thanks,